# Deserialize to IEnumerable<IEnumerable<CustomType>>

Tags: c#, json, generic-collections

Can anyone help me how to deserialize a json to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<CustomType>>`

I have a JSON object as shown below:

```
[
    [{"Role" : "RoleA"},{"Role" : "RoleB"}],
    [{"Role" : "RoleC"}],
    [{"Buyer" : "UserA"}]       
]
```

How do I deserialize to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<CustomType>>` where `CustomType` is

```
public class CustomType
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> AsJsonProperty()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {Type, Value}
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, i tried to do something like var readClaims = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<CustomClaimData>>>(metaData["ReadClaims"]);

Comment: And what happened when you tried that? You should [edit] that in to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot deserialise to an interface. Remember that they are effectively just a contract for a class to implement. Instead you should use a concrete class, such as `List<>`:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<CustomClaimData>>>(metaDat‌​a["ReadClaims"]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting back items but both the Type and Value property is null. How to map Type="Role" and Value="RoleA" when doing deserializing? Thanks

Comment: Your class doesn't match your JSON.

Comment: Yes. While seriazing i took only the values. While deserializing i want them to be mapped to respective properties

Comment: @MukilDeepthi  JSON does not work in that way, your original object should've been `[ [ { "Type" : "Role", "Value" : "RoleA" }, { "Type" : "Role", "Value" : "RoleB" }, ...], [...] ]`. This could be mapped properly.